# How to use conditional in Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, intermediate-language

Hello i am generating a class using `Reflection.Emit` and i want to know how do you use `brfalse` command for `conditionals`.

Specifically i do not know how do i translate the **IL** to **OPCODES** for the **brfalse.s** command.

My method has the following form:

`object MyMethod()
 {
  if(isTransaction)  //isTransaction is a bool property
  return Method1();
  else return Method2();
 }`

**Conditional**

```
        IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
        IL_0001: call         instance bool RediusTests.DaemonBase::get_IsTransaction()
        IL_0006: brfalse.s    IL_0020    //how is this translated within opcodes?
```

**First branch**:

```
        IL_0008:ldarg_0
        IL_.......          ///INSTRUCTIONS
        IL_......
        IL_001f:ret
```

**Second branch**:

```
        IL_0020:ldarg_0     //How do i specify with OPCODES to jump here?????
        IL_.......          
        IL_......
        IL_001f:ret
```

For the first snippet what would be the argument of `brfalse.s`?

```
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getIsTransaction);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse,);  //what do i put here in the overload?
```

As you can see  in the last snippet ,last line ,what should i put in the overload of `ilgen.Emit`? Nothing , **20** or is there some other code for translating to `IL_0020`?

Also isn't the address of the instruction stored at different address of memory on every run of program?Couldn't it change from `IL0020` to `IL00xx` at future executions?

**P.S** After receiveing some comprehensive answers this is my version so far:

```
        ILGenerator ilgen = newMethod.GetILGenerator();
        Label falseLabel = ilgen.DefineLabel();
        Label continueLabel = ilgen.DefineLabel();

        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);       
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getIsTransaction);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue,continueLabel);   //branching

        ilgen.MarkLabel(continueLabel);    //true branch
        ----instructions------
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Br,continueLabel);

        ilgen.MarkLabel(falseLabel);     //false branch
        --instructions----
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: IIRC brfalse.s should make short jump, i.e. a relative jump taking the difference between the offset of the target instruction and offset of the current/brfalse.s instruction.

Comment: You need to define and reference labels

Comment: But like @vc74 said if you use the Emit class you would need to define a label, so the Emit class can calculate the offset difference for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never have to deal with code addresses explicitly.
In order to jump, you need to define labels:

```
Label falseLabel = ilgen.DefineLabel();
Label continueLabel = ilgen.DefineLabel();

ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getIsTransaction);
ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse, continueLabel);

// getIsTransaction returned true
...

ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Br, continueLabel);

ilgen.MarkLabel(falseLabel);
// getIsTransaction returned false
...

ilgen.MarkLabel(continueLabel);
```

Comment: Oh i did not know.Thank you very much ! But why do you need the `ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Br,continueLabel)`?Don't you need just the `BrFalse` expression and the 2 `MarkLabel`-s ?

Comment: If you don't `br` after the true result handling, the false result handling will be executed too

Comment: And so the `MarkLabel`-s must be placed right before the first instruction of the `True` and `False` branch ?

Comment: Exactly, just like addresses

Comment: Ok so i would have : `brfalse` -> `MarkLabel(true) `->`[ branch instructions ..->ret ] `->`br`->`MarkLabel(false)`->` [  branch instructions ... ret]`?

Comment: You don't need the rets if it's all in a single method (unless you want to exit that method in which case you don't need the continue label)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180855/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-vc-74).